# is there a way to create database from django manage command?

Tags: python-3.x, django, multi-database

is there a way to create database from django manage command ?
i want create a multitenant Application and need to generate dynamic database configuration for  django manage command.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
   **'another_generated_from_manage_command'**:{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}

}
```

Comment: you want to create for each tenant its own database ?

Comment: yes I want to create a database foe each tenant dynamic

Comment: i think, in your context, for a given tenant, upon his signup, the database should be then  **automatically** created, via **template of database schema** not via `django` manage command ? but if you need it for some reasons have a look at this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases

Answer (score 0):

I am using multi-database one for development and other for production. However, I've never seen a command that is generated and configured by a python command.

Therefore, this is the approach I have done:

```
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    #Deployed DB
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
else:
    #Local DB
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            }
        }
```